How can I find out where a link redirects to without "visiting" it?
In short: I would like to find out the redirection target of links but want to make absolutely sure that the link target is not visited. How can I accomplish this and be absolutely sure that I have really accomplished it ?

background/context:
I sometimes receive http links in emails which purport to be sent from my friends but often are spam mails rather. (I don't know how these spammers succeed in spoofing their sender address so that it looks as if the mail came from my friends.) I don't want to click on any link in those messages, because sometimes the spammers use unique URLs in order to tie the click to the email message and thus confirm the active use of the email address. The result would likely be an avalanche of more spam messages.
The links are sometimes shortened. How can I find out where they redirect to without visiting the redirection target ? I.e. the redirection target must not be visited at all – neither by myself, nor by a third party service.
I know that some URL shortening services provide a "preview" function revealing the redirection target, e.g.:

goo.gl/xxxxxx --> goo.gl/xxxxxx+ (source)
bit.ly/xxxxxx --> bit.ly/xxxxxx+ (source)
tinyurl.com/xxxxxx --> preview.tinyurl.com/xxxxxx (source)

But what about those shortening services which lack a preview function, like t.co ?
There are web services like https://wheregoes.com which accomplish this task:

Have you ever wondered: Where does this link go? The URL redirect checker follows the path of the URL. It will show you the full redirection path of URLs, shortened links, or tiny URLs.



And apparently curl -I also accomplishes this task, according to these answers.
This is the output for curl -I https://t.co/0BACDYaBmU for example:
HTTP/2 301
date: Sat, 28 Dec 2024 00:20:17 GMT
location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
perf: 7402827104
vary: Origin
expires: Sat, 28 Dec 2024 00:25:17 GMT
set-cookie: muc=2ca1a41f-f6d2-452a-96d5-52589cd80dc5; Max-Age=34214400; Expires=Wed, 28 Jan 2026 00:20:17 GMT; Domain=t.co; Secure; SameSite=None
cache-control: private,max-age=300
x-transaction-id: 72964985cb99551e
strict-transport-security: max-age=0
x-response-time: 104
x-connection-hash: 7ee4ebd37aaafaeef618320e79e33949e8dcafcb48d4eeb096fe13be0d989081
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
set-cookie: __cf_bm=oc.td0GM68XbwPv2eDTJEAXGJhHosivnW0H2WaFJpjM-1735345217-1.0.1.1-lmI.FiF0dtpILwP3OJvz0qSRJ0.X1obCS3tf7eaoY_VqUXUOwoD.XeL1sNxQ7p_NGvj_2uk1vcIvNs.LWKuubQ; path=/; expires=Sat, 28-Dec-24 00:50:17 GMT; domain=.t.co; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
server: cloudflare tsa_o
cf-ray: 8f8d623a58aa5acd-VIE

But how can I be sure that by using either one of these 2 methods, the redirection target is not visited ?
I don't own a webserver nor would I have the skills to test this myself.
But is there a website which offers such a test online ?
related questions:

Is there any way to preview the URL of a t.co link on Twitter?
How can I find out what a goo.gl URL leads to, without visiting it?
How can I be certain that a URL-shortened link I click isn't going to send me to a dangerous or unwanted site?


I disagree about "This question needs to be more focused. Update the question so it focuses on one problem only." --> This questions does focus on 1 problem only: How can I find out the redirection target of links but make absolutely sure that the link target is not visited ?

Questions are supposed to include what the questioner has already tried so far. So I have included this information.

if you hover over a link does that not provide the target url? If the url indicated that way (usually at the foot of an email) looks wrong, it usually is and clicking on it may be the wrong thing to do. That's the basis on which I work and it served me well.

This will depend on the web app / URL shortener. I recommend modifying this question to focus on a specific URL shortener.
